# uilabel text inside a uiscrollview is not shown IOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am having a UILabel which contains long text. I want to embed into a scrollview and I am creating all of them programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
UIScrollView *myScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 305.0f, 290.0f, 304.0f)];
UILabel *centerLabel= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 305.0f, 290.0f, 304.0f)];

centerLabel.text=@" ... long text";
centerLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
centerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
[centerLabel sizeToFit];

myScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myScroll.contentSize.width, centerLabel.frame.size.height);
[myScroll addSubview:centerLabel];
[self.view addSubview:myScroll];
```

However, text is not shown. If I remove the scrollview text is shown, in the position I want.

So there is something wrong with my scrollview.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What is the resulting `contentSize` for myScroll?

Comment: @bobnoble width seems to be 0, but I do not undestand why from the above code. Do I forgot to set anything?

Comment: @bobnoble even if I manually set the width to a number inside myScoll.contentSize nothing is shown.

Comment: Did you mean to have `centerLabel`'s origin at 10/305 or 0/0? I'm wondering if it is outside the size of the screen, which it would be if this is running on an iPhone.

Comment: @bobnoble 10/305 is not outside of the screen. Without the scrollview it shows on the correct point. 10/305 is the top left coordinate, right, not the center point.

Comment: With the origin of the `frame` of `centerLabel` to 10/305, when added as a subview of `myScroll`, its position will be offset by 10 points from the left (x) and 305 points from the top (y) of `myScroll`, essentially making it fall completely outside bounds of the the scroll view.

Comment: @bobnoble yes you are right! Dimensions are relative to the scrollview. Make it an answer so I can accept it, if you want to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the origin of the `frame` of `centerLabel` to 10/305, when added as a subview of `myScroll`, its position will be offset by 10 points from the left (x) and 305 points from the top (y) of `myScroll`, making it fall completely outside bounds of the the scroll view.